# How to get the eigenvalues of the hessian of this functon

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to compute the eigenvalues of the hessian of the following function. Let 
$h(x,y,z,w):=-ln((x^{2}y^{2}+w^{2}+z^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}})$. I want to consider $-D^{2}h$. My questions is that :Is it possible to make the sum of the first three minimum eigenvalues of $-D^{2}h$ positive for $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+w^{2}$ small enough and $x^{2}y^{2}+w^{2}+z^{2}$ not equal to zero.

Comment: What are the *first three* eigenvalues? In any case, your first sentence is somewhat weird: to compute the Hessian you only need to compute derivatives!

Comment: the first three minimum eigenvalues

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question itself.